# How to allow customers information to be received by multiple emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, admin-panel

At present magento allowing only one email id to receive information but now I need information to be received by multiple emails is this possible?I made it possible for CONTACTS section by changing the .php file but I cannot able to find the file related to `store email address`

`I want to allow mulitple recipient emails for all the representatives in Store Email Address in admin section(Sales Representative,General Contact,Customer suport)`
please find below image.

[image]
Please help me,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most email services allow some kind of forwarding to multiple mail addresses.
So the best solution would be to create an forwarding for the address contact-list@something.com and then forward from there to all accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you mean,
If  you mean that you want mulitple recipient emails of orders sent to customers:
**system->configurarion->sales emails** in order tab add the emails to the field 'Send Order Email Copy To'.

Comment: My Question is :In magento how to add multiple recipients to 'Send Emails to' field in Email Options under "Store Email Address" Tab following options(Sales Representative,General Contact,Customer suport)

Answer (score 0):

You are in the wrong place in admin for what you are asking.  You can not set multiple send from addresses as your screenshot suggests.  That area is for setting your sending address.

For example, for multiple order email recipients you want to be at system > configuration > sales > sales emails